# Jobs page Remote filtering button functions only if you press label or checkbox

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design, filtering

The remote job filtering button on the [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page only works if you click the checkbox or label.

The other areas of the button is not effective.

[image]